# Delete Item Record AS400 Multiples

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have Item Records that have 2-4 lines per, and each line needs deleted.  My macro looks like this:

```
[pf23]
"3
[enter]
[pf3]
```

We have an OPT that requires  the "3, to delete from company database.  Not all items have the same line count, it varies between 2 and 4. Is there anyway to delete multiple item numbers, and each line for multiple item numbers?  I have a list of about 750 items to remove and I am estimating about 4 hours to complete the task.

I apologize if this is not the correct location to post this question.  Thank you!

Comment: I suppose "macro coding" is as much "programming" as any scripting language would be. But it would help if you'd edit your question with a couple screen-shot images so we'd know what we're working with. Upload images to an on-line photo site and put links in your question.

Comment: You want to read the screen and figure out how many other lines contain the same item as the one you've typed the '3' on, right?  AutoHotKey might be more flexible than IBM i Access for Windows.